# Rails database/model architecture conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, naming-conventions

I've got a database that I've been using and modelling, now I'm moving to Rails and am somewhat new at it.  What I'm looking for is a set of conventions around how Rails expects to treat database architecture in the three stages of dev, test, & prod.

Ie. Where does Rails expect the working version of the database to reside - inside a model or a database?  How is migration along the three stages handled?  Model naming / table naming conventions?  Primary key naming conventions?

I appreciate the help - cheers

Answer (score 1):

Rather than recreating what has been widely covered by others in such great detail, I would suggest you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database, which covers what you have asked about and more in great great detail.